# Hibernate throws NotWritablePropertyException when saving entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This happened to me other times, but this time the reason is different.

I reduced the scenario where it can be reproduced down to two entities, `Child` and `Parent`:

**Child:**

```
@Table(name = "Childs")
@Entity
@IdClass(KeyChild.class)
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    private int id0;

}
```

**Parent:**

```
@Table(name = "Parents")
@IdClass(KeyParent.class)
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private String id1;

    @Id
    private int id2;


}
```

**The composite keys:**

```
public class KeyChild implements Serializable {

    private KeyParent parent;
    private int id0;

}
```

and

```
public class KeyParent implements Serializable {

    private String id1;
    private int id2;

}
```

The problem happens when trying to save a Child (specifying the parent as you would spect).

An example controller:

```
@Controller
public class ParticiparController {


    @Autowired
    ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    ChildRepository childRepository;

    @GetMapping("/test/")
    public String evento() {

       Parent p = Parent.builder().id("test").id2(1).build();

       parentRepository.save(p);

       childRepository.save(Child.builder()
                .parent(p)
                .id(0)
                .build());

        return "test";
    }

}
```

The save method of the child repository throws:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id1' of bean class [com.example.myProject.Entities.Keys.KeyParent]: Bean property 'id1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I also tried without Lombok (just generating the getters and setters), but I got same result. I'm pretty sure setters are not the problem.

*Update:* There were, but not the entity ones... It seems that are only required in some cases.

Comment: Do you have getters/setters for the `KeyParent` ?

Comment: according to @SternK https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.4/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/NotWritablePropertyException.html

Comment: @SternK Omg, I didn't know that the setters were meant to be in the Key class, as it works fine when there's another type of parameters... Weird, but it worked. I was focusing so much on setters on entities... May you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it suggested in the error message you should have getters/setters in the `KeyParent` which correspond to the appropriate getters/setters of the `Parent` entity fields annotated by the `@Id`.